# How to customize primefaces page links?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

In our application we were loaded 20000 records in the primefaces data table but we faced some performance issue. so we planned to load the data page by page for that we sent start and end page number to back end and we got minimal records. On every page change we hit the Db and loads the data in data table.

First time i have sent 1 and 100, i got 100 records and total matched record count is 1800. i have set the list value in datable my page size is 50 and it shows the 2 page links in the data table. 
i want to set the page links dynamically based on the total matched record. but in primefaces it shows based on the datatable list size. how can i set the page links dynamically.

**My expected output:**

[image]

Comment: maybe a datatable with a lazy data model could help you https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: @David Florez: in that showcase they dont have a page links. My expectation is am having 10 rows but i want to add multiple page links.

Answer (score 0):

**Wanted:**
PF's [paginator](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml).

Example from website:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtPaginatorView.cars}" rows="10"
                 paginator="true"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
```

**Not wanted:**
Most JSF tags (not HTML, of course) support an attribute `styleClass="foo"` which can be used to attach a `class="foo"` attribute the resulting HTML tag.

Maybe that is what you need? Sorry, I have never attempted to modify these links (using PF6.0 CE).

Comment: And PrimeFaces have theme support, never done it on my side. :-/ Sorry that I cannot give you a 100% answer, just hints. :-)

Comment: Ah, now I got it. :-/ You want to have page 1-5, last and first displayed, I thought you want to change style! One second ...

Comment: I guess you want the "paginator" and customize it? Check this demo:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml

`<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtPaginatorView.cars}" rows="10"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">`